# Create a union when two properties have differently named types, but the same properties

Tags: typescript

I have two semi-complex types in my app that are named differently, but largely similar. They use sub-types that are identical. The types are auto-generated from graphql calls and the schema from the back end.

I'd like to create a function which can draw from either type and run a few operations on the properties that they share

Suppose the types look like this:

```
type dogType = {
__typeName: 'dogType',
doggoId: string, 
numLegs: dogNumLegsType,
tail: boolean
}
 
type dogNumLegsType: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
 
type catType = {
__typeName: 'catType',
kittyId: string,
numLegs: catNumLegsType,
tail: boolean
}
 
type catNumLegsType: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
```

Accessing a property like `tail` in my function is not an issue-- esLint sees no conflict, because both are boolean.

Accessing `numLegs` throws a conflict, as both are "different" types (despite having all of the same properties).

What is the best way to handle this when I know that I will need to perform logic based on the `numLegs` property? Is there a way to tell typescript to search for deep equality rather than strictly checking that they are of the same type?

Comment: Why do you have differently named, but identical types in the first place

Comment: The short answer is: Because of factors beyond my control that I didn't implement and that I cannot change. 

The longer answer involves treating our arguments for mutations as different types from the data supplied from GET endpoints.

Comment: Could you provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE?  Right now you say "throws a conflict" but I don't know what that means; it would be very useful to see an actual error message and its details, ideally in my own IDE when I look at the relevant code.  Right now the only problem with your example code is that it's got some syntax errors in it. (You also mention both TypeScript and ESLint, which are different... which one is causing your problem and what is the problem?)